# CMD/PowerShell: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have installed VSCode, VSCode Java extension, the newest version of Java, Oracle JDK.

When I type javac into cmd/PowerShell it says: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Also, when I search for the file "javac.exe", nothing comes up.

I have looked at other problems similar to this, although none of the people are having the exact same problem.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to add the Java bin location to the global PATH variable. So, you will be able to execute Java commands anywhere on the computer.

See: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml